# Adding images dynamically one by one

Tags: android

There are image buttons in an activity, I want to load images externally one by one.It means all the image buttons are invisible at first except the first one. After i click on the button i should be able to load images and after the image gets loaded on the button, the next button should get displayed. I achieved this for the first button, but unable to do it for rest of them. This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

ImageButton a, b, c, d, e, f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    a = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    c = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    d = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    e = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    f = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);

    a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


            ImageButton a = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            a.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            b.setVisibility(b.VISIBLE);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You somehow need to know the last clicked button so you can set the image and the visibility of the next. The following achieves that.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    ImageButton[] imgButtons;
    private ImageButton lastClicked;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgButtons = new ImageButton[6];
        imgButtons[0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imgButtons[1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        imgButtons[2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        imgButtons[3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        imgButtons[4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        imgButtons[5] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);

        for(ImageButton imgButton : imgButtons){
            imgButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        lastClicked = (ImageButton) v; // note, only possible because we only have imageButtons with click listener
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            if(lastClicked != null){
                lastClicked.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                int numButtons = imgButtons.length;
                for(int i=0; i<numButtons; i++){
                    if(imgButtons[i] == lastClicked && ++i < imgButtons.length){
                        imgButtons[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method which selects your image. Create one String global variable for example "`which`".

Like...

```
public void getImage(String whichbutton){
   Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            which=whichbutton;
}
```

Now call this method at every button click and pass button name.

In your onActivityResult change image as per which variable' value.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


if(which.equals("a")){
                ImageButton a = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
                a.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

                b.setVisibility(b.VISIBLE);
}else if(which.equals("b")){

 ImageButton b = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
                b.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

                c.setVisibility(b.VISIBLE);

}//and more


        }
```